# Display a QmessageBox alert when "toggle editing" is clicked

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, editing

I am required to display a QMessageBox.warning() as a reminder to update a specific field when "Toggle editing" is clicked. This is required for a project in QGIS. Currently, I just can display the QmessageBox to notice which layer is active

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox

from qgis.core import QgsProject

layer=qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()

QMessageBox.warning(iface.mainWindow(), "Capa Activa", 'La capa activa es ' +layer.name())
```

Comment: I guess your options here are edit the QGIS source code (and maybe make this behaviour switchable on a user option) or add a new action button via a plugin that pops up the dialog before enabling editing, and hiding or disabling the standard one.

Comment: @Spacedman No need to change QGIS source code, there is signal and slots in PyQGIS to connect a custom Python function to an existing event. I'm waiting for the question to open again.

Comment: @etrimaille indeed, I wasn't sure if clicking action buttons generated signals that could be caught in Python code... Q is reopened, happy hacking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "connect" your function to the signal `beforeEditingStarted` belonging to the QgsVectorLayer class.
https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a817d41d8320a54b2d51fbcb54e7fe2dd

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QMessageBox
from qgis.core import QgsProject

def start_editing():
    layer = iface.activeLayer()
    QMessageBox.warning(
        iface.mainWindow(),
        "Capa Activa",
        f'The layer {layer.name()} is now in editing mode.'
    )

layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.beforeEditingStarted.connect(start_editing)
```